# Loop Interval Out Of Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a looping chain of animations for a slideshow on the home page of a new build, for some reason my timing is out and all of the slides don't fade out at the end.

HTML

```
<canvas class="home-masked" width="186" height="183"></canvas>
<canvas class="home-masked2" width="186" height="183"></canvas>
<canvas class="home-masked3" width="186" height="183"></canvas>
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    function loop() {
        $('.home-masked').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500 );

        $('.home-masked2').delay(2500).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500 );

        $('.home-masked3').delay(5000).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500 );

        $('.home-masked3, .home-masked2, .home-masked').delay(5500).animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
    }
    setInterval(loop, 5500);
    loop();
});
```

I have a live preview here, wait to the end slide they should all fade out and restart.

http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~newlife/

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have added a link to a live preview

Comment: @Brent People can't edit the code in your live preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix `setInterval` or `setTimeout` with animations - there's no guarantee that the two timers will run on the same timescale.

You can remove the `setInterval` call and then use a "promise" attached to the elements to detect when the animations have completed and restart them by putting the following as the last line of the `loop()` function.

```
$('.home-masked3, .home-masked2, .home-masked').promise().done(loop);
```

With this formulation you can use an *immediately invoked function expression* to start it all off instead of an explicit call to `loop`:

```
(function loop() {

    // do animations here
    ...

    $(...).promise().done(loop);  // reinvoke myself
})();                             // start myself off
```

Comment: Can you suggest how I will get this looping perfectly then?

Comment: is this going where my fade out went?

Comment: No, if you still want the fade out to happen then this goes after.

Comment: Remove the set interval then?

Comment: @Brent dammit I've been making this harder than I meant to :(  I'm done now, reverted back to my original answer. Realised the second revision was too complicated.